# How can i put a Force Field between two items for Keyed particles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I made two objects and a controler using Keyed particles on Blender Cycles, and it works fine, because i wanted to make the particles going into another object so i don't want to change this.
What i want to know (and need) is to put a force field (for example a Curve Guide) between them to make a distortion on the ''Line'' of particles made by the keyed items, because it's still to static.
How can i activate it? Since i already added a force field, isn't working for me..

Please help!
Thanks in regard :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the physics set to newtonian, boids or fluid, particles are influenced by force fields and curve guides, while keyed particles only follow their own control systems. Keyed particle systems move particles from the position of one system to the position of another particle system. The key point is that you can use more than two systems for keyed particles.

By having a third system in the middle that uses newtonian physics I got the keyed particles to follow the middle particles as they followed the curve.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn't tried or even know the existence of that! Thanks!!