# Creating Inky-looking characters in Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, physics, blender-internal-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I'm involved in a project to do with ink animation and experimentation. I found this incredible piece of animation:

[Chinese Ink Style Animation](http://vimeo.com/6794856)

I originally thought this was some sort of After Effects compositing (is it even possible in AE?!), but found out that this particular animation was created in 3DS Max with Krakatoa and FumeFX. I'm just wonder if a similar effect is doable with Blender's smoke simulator.

There are various YouTube videos that have pretty decent results of ink renders from Blender, but I can't seem to find anything of a similar sort of movement animation. Just blobs floating around!
The closest thing I found was this animation of a

[Rigged Character Using Blender Smoke Sim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W18v8zkkbqI)

but again I can't seem to replicate this. The smoke just doesn't seem to follow my character's animation.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: This will take tons of computing power, absolutely insane. This is a very difficult effect to achieve well, and the number of particles necessary for a good result will kill your machine unless you own an animation studio, in which case you shouldn't be asking us for advice . . . It is theoretically possible with Blender however

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Thanks for your prompt answer. I suppose to get the smoke sim working with that amount of smoothness would take a ridiculously high resolution. I'll do a bit more research and see if there are similar ways to create an effect like that without requiring such extreme processing power!

Comment: No problem, I wish you luck! Feel free to post your findings here as updates (if it adds information) or as an answer.

Comment: @JacobW.E Yes, awesome animation what have you tried?

Comment: Gottfried Hofmann created an inkdrop tutorial a while ago Using a smoke generator and turbulence: http://blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/335-tutorial-a-cool-looking-inkdrop-in-blender.html A modified version of the file can be found here: http://blenderillusionist.blogspot.ca/p/free-stuff.html

Comment: it looks like they used a massive amount of particles, this can't be done in blender. But smoke sim could do something intersting with high res, low negative temp dif, smoke hires with low noise strengh, and wind. As it's only B&W for liquid, render time can be lowered with composited blur and playing with contrast.

Comment: I am working on a solution that doesn't use smoke sim, I will see how it turns out.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to use BI, or would cycles work as well?

Comment: Sorry for the late replies all, had a very busy couple of days.  

@stacker I found a couple of tutorials for ink drop effects and animations in Blender, but they all seemed to be randomised, as opposed to following the form of an actual character mesh.

Comment: @cegaton See my answer to stacker - I followed this tutorial and got a pretty neat result, but for some reason it didn't work when I tried to apply the method to a pre-made mesh, but I couldn't work out why.

Comment: @PGmath Cycles would be fine too. I'm just more comfortable with BI which is why I was trying with BI first. I am very interested in what you have come up with?

Comment: @Bithur thank you. They used 3DS Max, mo-cap, FumeFX and Krakatoa for that particular animation, so I am guessing that the particle count was pretty high!

Comment: @JacobW.E I am attempting to use a combination of volume scatter, abortion, and emission controlled by a mix of procedural textures.  So far it looks decent but I am trying to get rid of the sharp endings around the edges of the mesh and make it look more wispy.  I may just post what I have so far and continue working on it though.  I am not on my normal computer at the moment so I can't do it right now though.

Comment: @PGmath sure, I'd love to see what you've got, sounds like a totally different method! No rush though - I've got to head off for a bit now anyway.

Comment: @JacobW.E You may want to check out [this tutorial](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-fire-cycles/) to get used to smoke and cycles.

Comment: It's tagged "blender-internal" only (no cycles), can you confirm?

Comment: @Bithur apologies, I have updated tags. I was unable to put over 5+ tags on a post when I signed up (this was my first question), but now I have enough points or rep or whatever it is called, and have added the tag 'cycles'. Thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: @JacobW.E Unfortunately I can't quite work out a couple of the major problems with my approach yet.  I will continue working on it but I may just post what I have tomorrow.  It has several problems, but it is much faster and less intensive than doing a full smoke sim.

Comment: @PGmath I am interested in this and how you've worked around the huge amount of particles! There are some great answers to this question, but as you say they are extremely intensive using the smoke sim.

Comment: @JacobW.E Sorry I haven't posted yet!  I keep meaning to but I have been a lot busier lately than I had anticipated.  I will tey to get it up as soon as I can.  I am using a mixture of procedural textures (mainly wave) with high distortion values to get a swirly look (which can then be animated) to control the density of a mix of volume shaders (mostly scatter with a little absorption and emission).  The biggest problem is that it looks really bad around the edges of the model where the volumetrics come to an abrupt end.  You may end up having to use a tiny bit of smoke to fix that.

Answer (score 68):

If I understand correctly, your question is essentially asking how to emit smoke from a rigged and animated character.

This should work just fine, as long as the *smoke* modifier is **after** the armature modifier on the character mesh:

[image]

Example (click for a smoother video):

[image]
<sub>(source: [gfycat.com](https://fat.gfycat.com/DeepShallowBirdofparadise.gif))</sub>

I found using the mesh directly as the smoke emitter provided a smoother, less lumpy result without requiring huge numbers of particles.

## Smoke settings

<sub>All these settings are just stylizations on my part, they are not supposed to look like real ink in water :P</sub>

I used a fairly high resolution domain with only 1 *high resolution* subdivision, dissolve (though perhaps I made it dissolve a little on the fast side), and low vorticity:

[image]

For the emitter I used subframes and enabled *initial velocity* so that the smoke inherits the velocity of the part of the mesh it's emitted from (in the example render the smoke is actually "flung" by the mesh twice as fast as it technically should be, but I rather liked the effect). I also used a negative *temperature difference* so that the smoke drifts down over time, however I think I might have over done it a bit (the smoke falls a little fast for my taste).

[image]

Comment: One figure is worth thousand words. Nice shot gandalf3. :)

Comment: a bit smoky for now, needs more ink look. But quite cool!

Comment: @Bithur it looks more inky than smokey to me. Your impression is caused by the fast gif playback..imagine it slower and you have ink..The temp diff should be higher though so it doenst fall that fast but that does not change things..

Comment: @Bithur I would say that both you and jerryno are right - this looks like ink and smoke, but is definitely very close to the source reference footage I provided. Good job gandalf, gonna give this a go later!

Comment: Am I correct in guessing we have a new super hero on our hands? Suzy will need to get a name change though.

Comment: @AWildRolandiXor Suzink, the liquid ghost! :)

Comment: @gandalf3 could you [add a .blend :D](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: @gandalf3 This is in no uncertain terms *incredibly beautiful*. It is *so* close to what I am hoping is achievable in this question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62843/ink-on-porous-paper-or-water-bleed-effect Any chance of propagating this technique to less volume and having it paint?

Answer (score 33):

Emitting smoke from rigged character is a matter of having the smoke modifier **after** any other (having the smoke last in the stack means it will use the final mesh after all the modifiers):

[image]

When using mocap for character motion or by having constraints on the bones, the *subframes* setting for the *Flow* object won't work and you will get this:

[image]

To fix it bake the animation action for your bones with **Pose > Animation > Bake Action**. Use visual transform and delete constraints.

[image]

With this solved I will focus on **How to make smoke simulations really look inky**.

1. Every setting will depend on your *Domain resolution* and the size of your scene. That's why every showcase picture will have a downloadable .blend. Also the important settings are in bold.
2. **Enable *Initial velocity*** for every Flow object. We want the ink to carry the motion of each object.

   - Lower the *Surface emit distance* and set *Volume* to 1.
   - **Set *Temp. Diff* to -0.1** for every flow object so the smoke falls very slowly like ink in water.
   - You may also want to increase *Sampling Subframes* if your object moves fast.
   - For Ink Drop animations increase the *Source* above 1 and animate the *Density* from 1 to 0.

     [image]
3. Domain setting: 256 *Divisions*

   - ***Time Scale* around 0.3** (you may want to animate this for ink drops). Ink does not move as fast as smoke, this is important setting to make ink and not smoke.
   - Use **Low Vorticity**. This will be controlled with *Turbulence field* for the ink motion.
   - The ink can be nicely "faded" in post production, leave *Dissolve* unchecked or use some high number for *Dissolve* (like 150). Ink does not dissolve it will spread to thin with Turbulence field(s).

     [image]
4. **Add Turbulence field to the scene.** This will create the important "dissolve" motion for the ink:

   - Its important to not overpower the settings! Too small scale or too intensive and the ink will look more like smoke or like there is too motion in the water and like the ink does not dissolve naturally. These settings depends on your simulation dimensions. Its also good to animate the *Strength* if domain *Time scale* is animated.

     [image]
5. For *Domain material* use just *Absorbtion* volumetric shader with **High Multiply Value**:

   [image]

This results in ink like this (icosphere falling through domain):

[image]

<sub>[Download .blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34403)</sub>

Comment: can you add some images and examples of some of the steps?

Comment: Also the ink morphs from one object to another following the same apparent turbulence, any ideas?

Comment: @cegaton yep images are on todo, soon as I have them Ill add them. About that morphing I don't believe there is any. Its always faded or in camera cuts. I think the morphing text is in postproduction. I think of something though, maybe some shapekey morphing..

Comment: @cegaton [keyed particles](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21580/935) go from one shape to another, then choose particle system for the smoke emitter.

Comment: @sambler powerful but tricky. really intersting anyway

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a shot at this when I get home later and see what I can come up with.

Comment: still nothing to see but a screenshot from reference video :(

Comment: @Bithur outch, maybe I don't have that much time on my hands to do half day long simulations and rendering to get the result I want, do you want me to post some crappy fast pictures? If not than wait for it, I thank you for your patience.

Comment: Didn't want to hurt you, re-reading it, it's a bit harsh, sorry. I just wanted to see another approach. Thx for posting BTW :)

Comment: @Jerryno this looks great, thanks for the images and description!

Answer (score 22):

here is my reference animation:
[image]

Did a few tests and came back to particles.
[image]
Just changed velocity from object to 0.4 in particles settings:
[image]

Simplified and optimized things.
Here is the domain setting. Quite simple, not that hires with only 100 divisions and no smoke hires.

[image: domain setup]

The domain material is simple as well. Basic black volume absorbtion but smoke density modified with a color ramp.
[image]

The bird has 1 particle set. As it's a simple model with mirror, armature and subsurf, checked the "use modifier stack" option. Velocity from object looks better at 0.4 (see above render). Important settings are highlighted.

[image: particles]

The children have something special. Their number is animated from 0 to 5 and 0 again in 3 frames (very short) when i wanted the smoke to be more dense (when wings change direction).

The bird smoke settings:

[image: bird smoke emitter]

Compositing (vignette not included)

[image: compositing]

There's some really cool things with this setup. The "ink effect" (compositing) can be nice with a few render samples (used only 15). There's no light, no shadow (uncheck the option), only black smoke (added white background in compositing) renders in 5-10s for 25% HD size. The smoke sim is light weight too, 182Mo for 100 baked frames, and bakes fast.

About initial velocity : only working with emitter's surface and particles, not volume. Particles are better using no normal velocity but low object's velocity. Using children (simple, interpolated is for hair only) you need to check "rotation" and change the initial rotation to "normal" to get children poping at the surface of your faces.

Comment: this looks great! Could you possibly share some of your set up? I'm curious about the particle side of things. I've not got a lot of experience with particles, and getting the particles to move dependent on the animation of the model is totally outfoxing me.

Comment: as it's a WIP, it'll be completed through the process, i had to give an answer to put a screenshot.

Comment: @Bithur This is fantastic! Is the body emitting smoke or only the wings?

Comment: Both, 2 different system for better control