# Smoke and particle system with interpolated children

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, smoke-simulation

I'm using a particle system as a smoke emitter (see here [Creating Inky-looking characters in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24284/creating-inky-looking-characters-in-blender/24557#24557) ). Everything is fine but with simple particles, i don't have enough control on the movement of the smoke, so i need children. As simple children are really too ugly, i need interpolated children. But as soon as I activate them, all particles disapear from viewport and the simulation seems to use only parents (same as children deactivated).

no children:
[image]
Simple children:
[image]
Interpolated children:
[image]

My question is : is this a bug? can you use interpolated children in smoke sim?

Comment: Afaik, Interpolated Children is mainly for hairs. Not work well with emitters.

Comment: It's more than "not well" but i think you're true : not exactly a bug, no solution.

Comment: It's even worse for me, when I activate Interpolated all particles disappear, even the parents. @Bithur not sure why you say this is not a bug? If interpolated children don't work with emitter particles, at least the option shouldn't be available on the user interface IMO.