# Smoke physics interacting with particles?

Tags: particles, physics, smoke-simulation, hair

I have a scene where an ink drop effect created with smoke physics enters a scene with a fur ball created with the particle system. What I would like is to see the smoke interacting with the hair, pushing the strands without moving the object that the particles are emitting from. Is this possible?

Comment: Somehow related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24284/creating-inky-looking-characters-in-blender

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is what the "smoke flow" force field is for. Add one, point it at your smoke domain, and make sure hair dynamics is enabled on your particle emitter. If you don't want your hair to fall down due to dynamics being enabled, set the "gravity" field weight in the particles tab to 0. Note that all objects involved need to be on a single layer or else it won't work.