# Powder simulation

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation, color

I am trying to do a simulation for a powder spread out of capsules. I did a particle system alone and a smoke alone.
But I had two problems now. I need to make the smoke react with the particles to be more real like if I can make every particle have a little smoke around it?
And I couldn't change the color for the smoke even!? I did put too much light just to make it like that and I need it white.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using blender internal or blender cycles render ?

Comment: I am using cycles until now. @ShamsEl-Deen

Comment: There's a way to either base smoke physics on particles simulation (choosing particles system as flow source in the smoke emitter settings) or make particles follow smoke using Smoke Flow force field, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52257/smoke-physics-interacting-with-particles

Comment: Could you give a download to the .blend file?

Comment: When you say react do you mean that you want the smoke to apply force ( and thus generate movement) to your particles or do you mean you want the shader to produce a different look when the particles are in the smoke?

Comment: Try to use Molecular Script instead https://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-download/

Answer (score 1):

I created an example Scene with a smoke Simulation: You have to select the flow object and then change the flow source from mesh volume to Particle system [image]

[image]

and there you can also change the smoke color[image]

So there it is.[image]