# Ink on Porous Paper or Water Bleed Effect

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, fluid-simulation, dynamic-paint

I have seen some rather incredible results out there using smoke and dynamic paint, and as such, I am curious if anyone can come up with a clever simulation of ink onto paper, or, closely, ink into water.

## Brief

- Should create the look and effect of ink landing onto paper and dispersing via capillary action into the paper's texture.
- It must be accomplished in 3D via Cycles, and be modifiable / controllable.
- It should trace basic forms and result in an interpretable series of glyphs or shape.

## Sample

The following video is very close to the goal, with the potential to not bind quite as tightly to the water's path:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_zbcVs419E#t=2m20s

Here is another sample of the fractal-like expansion as the ink spreads through the medium. Very similar to ink landing on very thin tissue paper:

https://youtu.be/Nox0EFM0xow

Here is another of ink onto parchment. Ideally the effect would be possible to get in closer for a macro shot to observe the actual dispersion through the paper:

http://www.gettyimages.ca/license/181844542

I figure one of the clever minds around here would be able to generate something close to a viable solution.

Comment: @LukeD, as requested.

Comment: I tried passing a deformed sphere mesh through a plane as a paint source so that it would grow as the radius of the mesh increased (think flat lander POV) but fidelity was low. Perhaps distorted cycles textures driven by blend type textures would work?

Comment: Have you tried dynamic paint effects? https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/dynamic_paint/introduction.html

Comment: I have smoke sim pretty much accurate but I can't force dynamic paint to work with domain as a brush in cycles... I know nothing about Blender Render :/ If anybody knows how to use smoke in cycles with dynamic paint, I will do the rest.

Comment: I've got it, I'm making answer.

Comment: [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iw8hj2Uycvk) ink _in_ water, but I s'pose you meant _on_ water?

Comment: @ajwood on water on paper ;)

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24284/creating-inky-looking-characters-in-blender

Comment: @DuaneDibbley Looking more for a generated procedural result that offers the overall feeling of the expansion and traversal of ink through the water and paper as given in the videos. If you watch the zoomed in versions, you can see the fractal-like motion.

Comment: I've played a lot with this, but I don't have a complete solution... yet. But I do have a few ideas I'd like to share. Particles can be made to follow smoke, by use of a _Smoke Flow_ force field. Those particles can then be used as a brush for _Dynamic Paint_. Also, the paths of a **baked** particle system can be combed in _Particle Edit_ mode, just as you comb hair particles. Another idea is using two particle systems. One static with a _Harmonic_ force field emitted from the whole surface of the glyph, and one emitted from the drop of ink, which will be attracted to the glyph particles.

Comment: I think both of these answers are excellent, but I do *love* the idea of smoke painted. I believe @gandalf3 has some absolutely *excellent* attempts that I hope he posts as a solution. Would love to see the smoke attempts.

Comment: One of them looks more like Reaction Diffusion effect. While the other is like Fluid effect. Two different thing combined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: first]

After messing with settings.

### Basics:

To achieve 'ink drop on paper' effect we will be using *Fluid System* and *Dynamic Paint*. *Fluid* gives us nice control over drop shape. Blender units are used in this answer.

### Set up:

1. Plane with dimensions 8x8 - this is our 'paper' - it must be subdivided number of times (higher is better) I'm using 2 *Subsfurf* modifiers, first set to 6 and second to 2 both set as *Simple*, they need to be over the *Dynamic Paint* modifier.
2. Sphere (16 segments, 8 rings, 0.3 size), moved by 3 units over Z axis (<kbd>G</kbd> > <kbd>Z</kbd> > <kbd>3</kbd>) - this is our drop.
3. With selected Sphere hit <kbd>Space</kbd> search for *Quick Fluid* and apply.
4. Select *Domain* and *Scale/Position* it to cover whole plane.

[image: Set up]

### Fluid:

1. Select 'paper' (plane) and in *Properties tab* choose *Physics* then select *Fluid* and set *Type* to *Obstacle*. Decrease *Slip Type Amount* to 0.1
2. Select *Domain* and under *Fluid World* > *Viscosity Presets* set *Base* to 2 and *Exponent* to 3. Under *Fluid Boundry* set *Slip Type* > *Amount* to 0.03

**Exponent is very important here, if you want to preserve shape of your fluid you will need to set it to 0, and if you want to have random splatter set it higher.**

**Another important thing in Fluid Domain is Resolution, we will be using here 65 for preview but higher will give much better results**

### Dynamic Paint:

**Brush**

1. With selected *Domain* add *Dynamic Paint* (Physics tab).
2. Set *Dynamic Paint* to *Brush* and then *Add Brush*.
3. Change color if you want.
4. Under *Dynamic Paint Source* set *Paint Source* to *Proximity*, *Falloff* to *Color Ramp* and set *Color Ramp* as in the picture below:

[image: Brush]

**Canvas**

1. Select our 'paper' (plane) go to *Physics tab* and add *Dynamic Paint* > *Canvas* > *Add Canvas*.
2. Under *Dynamic Paint Advanced* set *Dry Time* to 25.
3. Under *Dynamic Paint Initial Color* choose *Color* and set it as you like.
4. Under *Dynamic Paint Effects* check *Use Spread* and set it to 0.5 then go to *Drip* and check it as well (it will give us control over the splatter by force fields).

[image: Canvas]

### Force field:

1. Add *Force Field* > *Turbulence* and set it to *Strenght* 10 and *Flow* 1.
2. Bake your fluid and play animation.

[image: Gif]
Domain and Fluid are hidden here.

[image]
Fluid resolution - 128 and some other sligt changes. This is from .blend file.

### Final thoughts:

There are many things to play with in order to get higher resolution/better looking effect as I mentioned it above. Fluid resolution, mesh (paper) subdivision, substeps in Canvas. You could change Influance Scale and Radius Scale under Canvas > Dynamic Paint Advanced to have 'lighter look' of ink. It's all up to you. Now when you know the method it will be fun to mess with it.

### Blend file:

[image]

Comment: This is darn close @LukeD. How can one constrain the bleed to a form, such as a letter etc?

Comment: I don't think I understand. Do you mean splatter shape? If yes just create this shape and make it as Fluid source and keep exponent to 0. Sorry I couldn't provide more detailed example, my PC seems to be to weak to this job :)

Comment: In the first video, the ink loosely follows a path. It would need to be constrained to a glyph or provide a way to constrain it.

Comment: Add in your question blend file with this mesh/glyph and I will try to adapt it. Con of this method is that you need change settings for every shape, resolution and such.

Comment: @LukeD It can be any old series of glyphs typed out frankly. Basically filling a text form would suffice. Ideally with a bit of bleeding beyond the form to keep it natural.

Comment: Instead of subdividing the paper mesh you can change the canvas format to image sequence and increase the image resolution for the final bake. You could setup collision objects to restrict the fluid flow to a shape you want. I expect using fluid physics for particles would be quicker than a fluid sim.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using paint I propose a modified mesh with textures.

[image: Glyph Bleed test]

1. Prepare your glyph art as white on a black field then use compositor to create an internal gradient for the shape (edge to center)

[image: Glyph prep]

2. Import this new "image as a plane" with emission settings (we won't be shading the result), unplug the image texture. Then apply simple subdivision and displace modifier from the imported texture. Then apply a remesh to cut the letter out from base. Finally apply another displace modifier with noise and gradient to limit effect.

[image: modify glyph object]
[image: Distort modifier texture]

3. Create and scale a box to use as a control object for texture mapping the glyph.

[image: Control object]

4. Select the glyph and edit the material to have the texture vector controlled by the Box object

[image: Ink material setup]

UPDATE 01: I have added another plane as a mask to eliminate the rough edges at the bottom

[image: mask glyph plane]

UPDATE 02: By adding another ramp to modify the distortion of the texture you can make the bleed at the edge occur quicker while the spread catches up. A more accurate result for the brief.

[image: Bleed improvement]

Comment: This would still require some post production to mask the edges of the glyphs as the are pretty coarse from the distort process. Also the control object can be easily rotated to make interesting wipe edges with texture bleed. And its all real time if you turn the samples down to 1.