# Blender equivalent of 'inflate' in Illustrator

Tags: mesh, extrude, 2d

Is there an equivalent in Blender of the 'inflate' 3D effect in Adobe Illustrator? e.g. to change a 2D object into a 3D one and give the same look as the below.

I've realised I can do it in Illustrator, export as a .obj and then import that into Blender, but would prefer to know how to do it without switching between programs.

I've tried using the bevel feature but it just seems to inflate it from outside the edge if that makes sense.

I've also tried using `inflate` sculpting on a 2D plane, but it just gets a bit messy

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72662/trying-to-make-glossy-volume-shapes  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134971/round-beveled-text https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142071/how-to-get-this-type-of-relief/142084#142084