# How to create a realistic looking Ink spill from a bottle?

Tags: texturing, materials, glass, mantaflow

I've been working on a project for the past couple of days and I would like to know a way to create a realistic ink spill/splash from a bottle.

I tried using Mantaflow and it came out looking like this.
It doesn't quite look like ink. I used the viscosity of water and also reduced the upres value.

[image]

What I'm actually looking for is something like this or atleast close to it.

[image]

I would also like to know how to create the tiny particles or residue inside the bottle left by the ink. I tried duplicating the entire inner portion of the bottle and adding another material to it. But it doesn't work.

I hope somebody looks into this.

Comment: is this for animation or a still image? The ink looks different because in the render the ink runs on the surface, whereas in the reference image the ink has already been partially soaked up by the paper and this leads to a color bleed.

Comment: Try to add the bleed what Blunder mentioned with dynamic paint.

Answer (score 4):

You could also try volumetrics and an image texture.

1. Use an [image texture](https://www.google.com/search?q=ink%20splotch&tbm=isch) for the color bleed
2. Give your ink spill a *Glass Shader* and a *Principled Volume* shader
3. Use a texture to drive the volume's *Density* (there's more ink on one end)

[image]

<sup>Ink spill node setup using Principled Volume</sup>
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here the resource-intensive approach with a *Fluid* simulation and *Dynamic Paint* for running ink on paper (Eevee render).

[image: screenshot of the ink]

The fluid is a brush and paints on the paper plane. The setup is similar as described in the question [Ink on Porous Paper or Water Bleed Effect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/62843/107598), but there is only the proximity effect (Source > Proximity `0.5`, *Falloff* `Smooth`), no *Spread* and no *Drip* effects.

The fluid simulation has default values, except for *Settings > Resolution Divisions* (`48`), and a smaller Liquid > Particle Radius of `0.800` to make the ink soak in (disappear) faster.

For the color bleeding the vertex color "*dp_wetmap*" of *Dynamic Paint > Output* is mixed up with a *Noise Texture*. The result is used for a *Bump Map* and colorized with a *Color Ramp* and *MixRGB* nodes, and blended with the [paper image texture](https://cc0textures.com/view?id=Paper002).

[image: ink shader]

The ink (liquid) has a transmission/glass material with a green base color which appears almost black.

Animation test:
[image]

Comment: must've missed this one, very nice result! :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe create an *Image Texture* in order to draw a transparent border all around the ink spot, use it as a mix factor between *Diffuse* and *Transparent* nodes, or use vertex paint to do the same, and behind that give it a *Glossy* node:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me try it. In the meantime how can I do the second part i.e. the tiny particles and residue left in the bottle by the ink?

Comment: maybe same thing? use a b&w mask that let see a black deposit? you just need to make the mask a bit noisy