# Can particles behave as if in air - like smoke

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to recreate this effect in Blender (cycles):

https://www.reddit.com/r/Simulated/comments/44k95b/crow/

I've animated a mesh using AnimAll, and used it as a particle emitter with wind from the front, but can't seem to get the emitted particles to behave as if they're in air - with the vortexes and swirls you'd associate with e.g. smoke.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
Any ideas ?

Comment: Could you post what you have so far? Some animation would be great.

Comment: Which physics have you set for your particles? Have you also set a force field, and which?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24284/creating-inky-looking-characters-in-blender

Comment: Normal particle emmitter on the mesh, and I've tried to combine the partice system with a 'smoke flow' but to no avail.

Comment: Thanks @cegaton for the link - some beautiful animations referenced there, and I have a lot to work on now