# How can I make a silky, wispy smoke effect?

Tags: particles, physics, smoke-simulation

A while back, I asked a question about how to make an effect of blood in the water. No one answered, so I assume that the question was too specific. I've elected to delete that post in favour of a more general question concerning this effect.

Blender's smoke simulation seems to only give cloudy results--while I'm looking for a way to create an effect similar to these images I've found across the web:

[image: Examples]

What kind of settings would a smoke simulation require to have this?

And if it turns out that I can't make this silky, wispy, ghostly-strand effect because of limitations of the smoke simulator, is there a way I cheat and do this effect with particles and render them in a way that they appear like smoke?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24284/creating-inky-looking-characters-in-blender