# Transforming Objects Into Other Ones

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How would you animate a cube in Blender Cycles Engine to transform it smoothly into a human model I already made?

Comment: If you mean exploding meshes and recombining them afterwards then this could be related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42349/mesh-breaking-apart-and-recombining-to-form-another-mesh. If morphing, i.e. smooth transition, then Cast modifier (probably along with Shrinkwrap) really can be your first option to consider.

Answer (score 3):

Best bet is to use the **Cast Modifier** to morph the cylinder into a sphere shape.

The trick to get it to work well is:

1. Have a good number of evenly spaced edge loops along the cylinder length as well as concentric edge loops on both caps
2. Then set the mesh surface shading to Smooth and add a 1 level **Subsurf Modifier** before the Cast Modifier
3. Select Sphere as the cast type and then you can keyframe the Factor from 0 to 1
4. You may need to increase the Radius amount if the cylinder is longer than my example.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do more complicated mesh too like if you have a model of a human to transform them into a cube?

Comment: You might have to use a shape key animation on the human mesh to get it closer to the cube shape before using the cast modifier technique.

Comment: How would that be done? Wouldn't I have to remodel the whole human again starting out with a cube to use shape keys?

Comment: @AustinH. please [edit] your original question so that it reflects what you really want to do.

Comment: Okay, edited the question.

Comment: @AustinH. You wouldn't necessarily have to start with a cube and remodel your human. You could just turn the human you have into a cube ;-)

Comment: How would that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Select your model and go to Properties->Data->Shape Keys. Click "add" 2 times. Select the second shape key and go into edit mode. Now transform your mesh until it looks like a cube. Do not remove any vertices. Leave edit mode. You can now animate the "value" slider to switch between both states. You most likely want to add more shape keys to make the animation smoother.

If you can't put your model into a perfect cube form, add a cube to the second shape key and scale your model down until it's completely hidden in the cube.