# How to transform an object into another

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How would you make a lizard smoothly transform into a fish in the blender cycles engine? I have seen animators do similar transformations like this and I have always wondered how. Whenever I try to look up how it is done there are no tutorials on it.

Comment: I think they do it with shape keys,not sure though.

Comment: It's definitely shape keys, there are some good video tutorials out there.

Comment: Is this the same question as your [previous post?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52355/transforming-objects-into-other-ones)

Comment: It is similar but different

Comment: The other post involved 2 separate shapekeys while this one involves joined shapekeys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Austin H. the correct answer to this would be using shape keys. Jonathan Williamson from CGCookie has made an excellent tutorial on that some years ago. [Here](https://vimeo.com/16783367) is a direct link to it on vimeo.

Comment: Thanks, how would you give both meshes an equal amount of vertices? For example if I had text that said text and another text object that said hi and I wanted the text to turn into hi.

Comment: If I would do a morphing animation where a lizard would turn into a fish I would start with roughly the same base mesh and go from there. There's always a way to increase the vertex count on some areas. Another but somewhat "dirty" method would involve using a shrinkwrap modifier.

The whole text to another text morph is a totally different thing. Last time I checked nobody came up with a simple solution in form of simply applying a modifier and you're done. I would certainly welcome such an awesome solution.